# How is Snowflake rolling back a truncate operation?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have some code, below, that appears to be able to roll back the effects of a truncate statement, which is somewhat surprising. Can someone explain why the code is able to do this? From my reading of the docs describing Snowflake transactions, this should not be possible.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE foo(a int);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
BEGIN TRANSACTION;                                                                                                                                    
INSERT INTO foo(a) VALUES (1);                                                                                                                        
INSERT INTO foo(a) VALUES (2);                                                                                                                        
INSERT INTO foo(a) VALUES (3);                                                                                                                        
COMMIT;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
SELECT * FROM foo; -- Table contains three rows                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
TRUNCATE TABLE foo;                                                                                                                                   
INSERT INTO foo(a) VALUES (4);                                                                                                              
SELECT * FROM foo; -- Table contains one row
ROLLBACK;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
SELECT * FROM foo; -- Table contains three rows
```

Comment: If you use Begin Transaction, put your code between that and the COMMIT, and it creates a block of code that allows for use of Rollbacks.  Its an inherent MySQL feature and not specific to anything google has done, afaik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TRUNCATE TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-dml) is a DML operation and does not commit an active transaction.

> **General DML**
>
> Commands for inserting, deleting, updating, and merging data in
> Snowflake tables:
>
> - INSERT
> - INSERT (multi-table)
> - MERGE
> - UPDATE
> - DELETE
> - **TRUNCATE TABLE**

---

[Transaction - Terminology](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions#terminology):

> The term “DDL” includes CTAS statements (CREATE TABLE AS SELECT ...) as well as other DDL statements.
>
> The term “DML” refers to INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, MERGE, and TRUNCATE statements.

and:

> Note
>
> Explicit transactions should contain only DML statements and query statements. **DDL statements implicitly commit active transactions (for details, see the DDL section).**

Side note: There are RDBMSes which clasify `TRUNCATE` as DDL.

Comment: And -1 to me for assuming Snowflake was one of them! In fact it's the first time I've come across one that doesn't classify TRUNCATE as DDL. I wonder how many other assumptions I've brought from other DBMS systems that aren't the case in Snowflake :o

Answer (score 1):

Yes, confusing, but once you get a hang of it… When you perform a TRUNCATE TABLE operation inside a transaction, the effect isn't visible immediately to other sessions or transactions. The TRUNCATE operation marks the table, but the actual truncation doesn't happen until the transaction is committed.